# SOAP Security negotiation with service for target failed

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm calling an external web service from my .NET client. The hoster is using a self-signed certificate and they say I don't need to install any certificate to call their service.

All my client and service configuration is in my app.config file, so I'm creating the client without any binding or end point address as parameters. I'm also using a service reference.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ServiceReference.BgLinkServiceClient client = new ServiceReference.BgLinkServiceClient();

        ServiceReference.LogonRequest request = new ServiceReference.LogonRequest();
        ServiceReference.LogonResponse lg = new ServiceReference.LogonResponse();

        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to connect to the Service...");
        lg = client.Logon(request);
    }
```

My app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MessageTransportBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding_IBgLinkService">
      <reliableSession />
      <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic256Sha256" authenticationMode="SecureConversation"
          requireDerivedKeys="true" includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
          requireSignatureConfirmation="false" canRenewSecurityContextToken="true">
        <secureConversationBootstrap defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic256Sha256"
            authenticationMode="AnonymousForSslNegotiated" requireDerivedKeys="true"
            includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
            requireSignatureConfirmation="true">
          <localClientSettings detectReplays="true" />
          <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" />
        </secureConversationBootstrap>
        <localClientSettings detectReplays="true" />
        <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" />
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint 
      address="https://www.bt.bglinkws.bgonline.se/WebService/BgLinkService.svc"
      binding="customBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IBgLinkService"
      contract="ServiceReference.IBgLinkService" 
      name="CustomBinding_IBgLinkService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="www.bt.bglinkws.bgonline.se" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I'm getting this error:
SOAP security negotiation with 'https://www.bt.bglinkws.bgonline.se/WebService/BgLinkService.svc' for target 'https://www.bt.bglinkws.bgonline.se/WebService/BgLinkService.svc' failed.

Inner Exception:
{"The X.509 certificate CN=www.bt.bglinkws.bgonline.se, OU=ITS, O=Bankgirocentralen BGC AB, C=SE chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.\r\n"}

Could use some help here, been struggling with this for a while.